# SAML with Tomcat in Azure WebApps

Tags: azure-web-app-service, saml, tomcat8, onelogin

I am publishing an application using Tomcat8.5 with Azure Webapps. In addition, I am using ONELOGIN as the SP for SAML authentication, but when the minor version of Tomcat was updated to 8.5.58, an error occurred and I could not authenticate.
The error message is as follows.

"The response was received at http://example.com/postauth.do instead of [https://example.com/postauth.do"](https://example.com/postauth.do%22).

I had the same problem before and was able to work around it by adding the following setting to Web.xml, but since 8.5.58, I can no longer work around it.

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>RemoteIpFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteIpFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>remoteIpHeader</param-name>
            <param-value>x-forwarded-for</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>remoteIpProxiesHeader</param-name>
            <param-value>x-forwarded-by</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>protocolHeader</param-name>
            <param-value>x-forwarded-proto</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>RemoteIpFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Currently, I have fixed the version to 8.5.57 to avoid the error, but I would like to know how to avoid the error in 8.5.58 and above.

Best regards.

2021/10/28 Update.
This is the error image when I updated the server.xml in KUDU and tried to save it.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the Tomcat upgrade is the only thing that changed? There are no changes in the `RemoteIpFilter` between those versions. I would guess that the configuration of the reverse proxy/load balancer changed.

Comment: Only version changes were implemented. No other changes have been made. 8.5.57 confirms OK, 8.5.58 confirms NG.

Answer (score 0):

There is no changes in `RemoteIpFilter` in recent times. Check for fixes [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/security-8.html)

You can follow the below steps to **to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS for Enforce UI**

1. Go to `\tomcat\conf` directory in kudu

[image: directory_1]

2. Edit the file **server.xml**
3. Add the following above the first `< connector>` entry:

< !-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 80 -->

```
< Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="80" acceptCount="100" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="150" redirectPort="443" />
```

4. Save the **server.xml** file.
5. Edit the **web.xml** file in the same directory

[image: directory_2]

6. Scroll to the bottom of the file and add the following just above the `< /web-app>` entry:

< !-- Force HTTPS, required for HTTP redirect! -->

```
< security-constraint>  
< web-resource-collection>  
< web-resource-name>Protected Context</web-resource-name>  
< url-pattern>/*< /url-pattern>  
< /web-resource-collection>  
  
< !-- auth-constraint goes here if you require authentication -->  
< user-data-constraint>  
< transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>  
< /user-data-constraint>  
< /security-constraint>
```

7. Save the **web.xml** file
8. Restart the app service and check now.

Refer here [for more info](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/162130/configure-tomcat-to-redirect-all-http-re.html)

Comment: I tried to edit the server.xml file, but could not because I do not have access rights. How did you edit it?
In the case of Azure WebApps, it is a PaaS service, so I think it is natural that you cannot edit the server configuration file.

Comment: You can edit the Paas web app files in azure using KUDU. PaaS doesn’t set up a virtual machine that you can remote into in the traditional sense and instead abstracts all that complexity away for you. Enter the [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki) Service Dashboard. Refer [here](https://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/How-to-add-edit-and-remove-files-in-your-azure-webapp-using-the-kudu-service-dashboard/)

Comment: I know about KUDU and use it. However, I can only edit files under D:/HOME with KUDU, and when I try to edit files in other paths, I get the following error.

"ERROR

409 Conflict: Could not write to local resource 'D:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.58\conf\server.xml' due to error 'Access to the path 'D:\ Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.58\conf\server.xml' is denied.'"

Do you have a different version of WebApps or something else? The path you gave me as an example was also the C drive, so I'm thinking it may be a different environment.

Comment: If we using Tomcat which not from marketplace, the Tomcat path is **D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-X.0.X** which can't be operated by user role and we get the administrator permission.

However, creating App with Tomcat from **marketplace**, Tomcat will exists at the path **D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin** which we have the write permission. Please check the Official Doc for [custom Java web app to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common)

Comment: I have never deployed Tomcat by selecting it from the marketplace, and this is not the way my company rules.

So I am wondering if I can do something with the web.xml setting of the application instead of the server.xml or web.xml setting of Tomcat.

Comment: In the case of Tomcat8, 8.5.87 and 8.5.88 were the boundaries. Similarly, for Tomcat9, the borderline was 9.0.37 and 9.0.38. Since 8.5.88 and 9.0.38 were updated with almost the same content, it seems that the content of the update has some effect. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes you can use the latest version Tomcat 10 also, check [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/security-10.html#Fixed_in_Apache_Tomcat_10.0.12).

Comment: I found that javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL() behaves differently in 8.5.57 and 8.5.58. If I add a RemoteIPFilter setting to web.xml, the 8.5.57 getRequestURL returned https, while 8.5.58 returned http. I would like to know why the behavior is different.

Comment: I'll upload this as a Tomcat question. I will feed back here when it is resolved.